# How to display the rss version of a News Link

Tags: php, drupal, rss, joomla

I'm trying to write a script that will show the rss version of a single url (title, author, image, source, etc..). This should behave much the way that facebook does when you copy paste a link to share and it generates this information automatically. I'm trying to do this with a php script but would also be open to opensource programs that can do this as well.

also, if anyone knows of any Joomla/Drupal plugins that can do this that would be great. This may eventually end up on a site run on one of these frameworks.

thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what you're asking for, but here is a list of Joomla extensions that handle RSS syndication:
[link text](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/content-sharing/rss-syndicate)

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a pretty specific application to get started with a big framework. Anyway, some Drupal modules worth checking out:

- http://drupal.org/project/facebook_link
- http://drupal.org/project/views
- http://drupal.org/project/views_rss